# Cross Context LINQ Joins in Azure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, azure

We're currently migrating our production platform to Azure, and as such I need to move over all of our support tools. Previously, we relied heavily on data adapters and stored procedures, and many of these stored procedures performed cross-database joins.

With our migration to Azure, none of these cross-database joins are operational. I tried moving our data adapters to Entity Framework, but I cannot seem to make them work. Instead, I get an error stating that cross-context joins are not allowed. Many of these queries rely on data from multiple databases, so I'm just trying to figure out what the best method of approach is to get this operational.

I've looked at several of the other questions asking for similar solutions, but none of them seem terribly applicable to my solution.

For example, here's one of the more simple queries in SQL:

```
USE CustomerDB1234
SELECT DISTINCT u.[UserID]
  ,u.[UserLogin]
  ,u.[UserPhoneNumber]
  ,u.[UserPasswordHash]  
  , ISNULL(gl.[gl_login_name],'* no global login ID') AS [gl_login_name]
  ,gl.[gl_password_hash]
  ,gl.[gl_GUID]
  ,gl.[gl_Email_Validated]
  ,u.[usr_unit_set_id]
  ,oob.[oob_org_id]
FROM [dbo].[User] u WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[OrganizationObjectBridge] oob WITH (NOLOCK) ON oob.[oob_object_type_id] = 9 AND oob.[oob_object_id]= u.UserID  
LEFT JOIN [MainServer].[MainDb].[dbo].[GlobalLoginCustomerBridge] glcb WITH (NOLOCK) ON glcb.[glcbr_user_id] = u.UserID
    AND glcb.[glcbr_customer_id] = dbo.efnGetCustomerID()
LEFT JOIN [MainServer].[MainDb].[dbo].[GlobalLogin] gl WITH (NOLOCK) ON gl.[gl_id] = glcb.[glcbr_gl_id]
WHERE ([UserID] = @userID OR @userID IS NULL)
    AND ([UserDisabled] = @isDisabled OR @isDisabled IS NULL)
ORDER BY [gl_login_name]
```

And in Linq, it would look similar to:

```
List<User2> userList = new List<User2>();
using (var e = new eContext())
using (var context = new CustomerContext(CustomerID))
{
    var databaseConnections = e.DatabaseConnectionStrings;
    var customer = e.Customers.Select(n => new
    {
        ID = n.CustomerID,
        Name = n.CustomerName,
        Email = n.CustomerEmail,
        Website = n.CustomerWWW,
        Logo = n.CustomerLogo,
        DatabaseConnectionName = databaseConnections.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DatabaseConnectionID == n.DatabaseConnectionID).DatabaseConnectionName,
        DatabaseConnectionString = databaseConnections.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DatabaseConnectionID == n.DatabaseConnectionID).DatabaseConnectionString1,
        AccountNumber = n.CustomerAcctNumber
    }).FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == CustomerID);

    userList = context.Users
        .Join(e.GlobalLoginCustomerBridges,
            u => u.UserID,
            glcb => glcb.glcbr_user_id,
            (u, glcb) => new { u, glcb })
            .Where(n => n.glcb.glcbr_customer_id == CustomerID)
        .Join(e.GlobalLogins,
            glcb => glcb.glcb.glcbr_gl_id,
            gl => gl.gl_id,
            (glcb, gl) => new { glcb, gl })
        .Join(context.OrganizationObjectBridges,
            glcb => glcb.glcb.u.UserID,
            oob => oob.oob_object_id,
            (glcb,oob) => new {glcb, oob})
            .Where(n=>n.oob.oob_object_type_id == 9)
       .Select(n => new
       {
           ID = n.glcb.glcb.u.UserID,
           GlobalLogin = n.glcb.gl.gl_login_name,
           FirstName = n.glcb.glcb.u.UserFirstName,
           MiddleName = n.glcb.glcb.u.UserMiddleName,
           LastName = n.glcb.glcb.u.UserLastName,
           GUID = n.glcb.gl.gl_GUID,
           UserID = n.glcb.gl.gl_id,
           HasSHA256Hash = n.glcb.gl.gl_password_hash_sha256 == null,
           Customer = customer,
           Organization = context.Organizations
               .Select(o => new
               {
                   ID = o.org_id,
                   Name = o.org_name,
                   ParentID = o.org_parent_id,
                   ExternalID = o.org_external_id,
                   Default = o.org_default,
                   Logo = o.org_logo,
                   URL = o.org_url,
                   PeerGroupID = o.org_peer_grp_id,
                   ExternalInfo = o.org_external_info
               }).Cast<Organization2>().FirstOrDefault(o=>o.ID == n.oob.oob_org_id)
    }).Cast<User2>().ToList();

}
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420637/complex-linq-queries-across-multiple-contexts-and-collections)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Perform the joins in the application in memory. Depending on the query this is more or less efficient. Also, the code changes required range from tiny to terrible.
2. Merge databases together. Having many databases without a physical reason for that is an anti-pattern. Databases are not logical units of application modularization. Document modularization through schemas or table name prefixes. Databases are physical units of deployment.

Third approach: Run a SQL Server in a VM.

Comment: As for option 2, this is a bit more problematic. I have no say-so when it comes to our schema, we have a full team of developers focusing on that side of things and I'm merely here to write tools for our support team. However, our schema is comprised of essentially 1 main database that houses shared data and hundreds of single-tenant databases that hold data for each individual customer.

Comment: And I assume you need to query 1 tenant and the shared db together?

Comment: Generally yes, in some cases I may need to query 2 tenants, but this is considerably more rare. In our older code-base, when things were hosted locally, we could use linked servers, but this feature doesn't exactly exist in Azure. I posted one of the more simplistic queries in my question above.

Comment: You're in a bad spot. In my mind SQL Azure is the nuclear option. Gets rid of a lot of maintenance but also kills a lot of features and flexibility. Decide for yourself...

Comment: I'm just not even sure where to start with some of these more inter-related joins.

Answer (score 1):

By using the information posted by the other answer, I came up with a solution that appears to work. Granted, it doesn't appear nearly as efficient or as concise as cross-database joins, but it gets the job done.

```
using (var context = new CustomerContext(CustomerID))
using (var e = new eContext())
{
    var globalUserList = e.GlobalLoginCustomerBridges
        .Join(e.GlobalLogins,
            glcb => glcb.glcbr_gl_id,
            gl => gl.gl_id,
            (glcb, gl) => new { glcb, gl })
        .Where(n => n.glcb.glcbr_customer_id == CustomerID)
        .Select(n => new User2
        {
            ID = (int)n.glcb.glcbr_user_id,
            GlobalLogin = n.gl.gl_login_name,
            GUID = n.gl.gl_GUID
        }).ToList();

    var customer = e.Customers
        .Join(e.DatabaseConnectionStrings,
        c => c.DatabaseConnectionID,
        d => d.DatabaseConnectionID,
        (c, d) => new { c, d })
        .Select(n => new Customer2
        {
            ID = n.c.CustomerID,
            Name = n.c.CustomerName,
            DatabaseConnectionName = n.d.DatabaseConnectionName,
            DatabaseConnectionString = n.d.DatabaseConnectionString1,
            GUID = n.c.cust_guid,
        }).ToList().FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == CustomerID);

    var orgs = context.Organizations
        .Select(o => new Organization2
        {
            ID = o.org_id,
            Name = o.org_name,
        }).ToList();

    var users = context.Users
        .Select(n => new User2
        {
            ID = n.UserID,
            FirstName = n.UserFirstName,
        }).ToList();

    var userList = users
        .Join(globalUserList,
            u => u.ID,
            gl => gl.ID,
            (u, gl) => new { u, gl })
        .Join(context.OrganizationObjectBridges,
            u => u.u.ID,
            oob => oob.oob_object_id,
            (u, oob) => new { u, oob })
            .Where(o => o.oob.oob_object_type_id == 9)
        .Select(n => new User2
        {
            ID = n.u.u.ID,
            GlobalLogin = n.u.gl.GlobalLogin,
            FirstName = n.u.u.FirstName,
            GUID = n.u.gl.GUID,
            Customer = customer,
            Organization = orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == n.oob.oob_org_id)
        }).Where(n => !isDisabled != null && n.Disabled == isDisabled).ToList();

    return userList;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. It's not fun and sometimes you'll fall into an efficiency trap where you have quadratic time complexity but the database previously did it in linear time due to query optimization. Be sure to test before deploying :)

Comment: `orgs.FirstOrDefault...` looks to be such a case. Join is generally faster because it uses a hash table internally.